# getView() of BottomSheetFragment

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater, bottom-sheet

I am implementing app with `BottomSheetFragment` and cannot understand where I can get access to the measured root `View` of the fragment. The problem is that `onViewCreated()` does not invoked. And `getView()` in `onAttach()`, `onActivityCreated()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` return null. 
My code of `setupDialog` method:

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), getContentResource(), null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
}
```

Comment: `onViewCreated()` would be called only when the view returned from `onCreateView()` is not null

Comment: I've successfully managed to regroup initialization of my `Fragment` but I don't know where I can get height of the `View`.

Answer (score -1):

You can it get from the `onCreateView` of the fragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);

    //Your code here


    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Here it not attached to any of parents, so if you could try to getHeight() that is not fixed(match_parent, wrap_content), it return 0.